# Full outer join not including results from the second table?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have 2 employee tables and trying to look up a user from both of them. For example:

Employees1

```
username          full_name
fbar              Foo Bar
```

Employees2

```
email             full_name
sname@test.com    Some Name
```

I'm trying to do something like this:

```
DECLARE @testuser VARCHAR(100)
SET @testuser = 'sname'

SELECT isnull(a.full_name, b.full_name) as full_name
FROM Employees1 as a
FULL OUTER JOIN Employees2 as b ON b.email LIKE @testuser + '%'
WHERE a.username = @testuser
```

If I run this then it comes out blank. But if I run the following then it shows the correct name:

```
SELECT full_name FROM Employees2 WHERE email LIKE @testuser + '%'
```

Is there a reason the `full outer join` isn't showing a result but the second select statement is?

Comment: `WHERE a.username = @testuser` turns your `FULL OUTER JOIN` into a `LEFT JOIN`.

Comment: Try running your query without the `where` clause then visualise the effect of that additional criteria.

Comment: Filter could be moved to join

Comment: Back on topic: I suspect a `JOIN` isn't what you want here. More like you want a `UNION ALL` and each query has its own `WHERE`.

Answer (score 0):

If you have limiting conditions on individual tables that are separate from the outer join condition, you will need to put them in a subselect for them to work as expected.

I believe what you want is something like:

```
DECLARE @testuser VARCHAR(100) = 'sname'

SELECT isnull(a.full_name, b.full_name) as full_name
FROM (
    SELECT *
    FROM Employees1
    WHERE username = @testuser
) as a
FULL OUTER JOIN (
    SELECT *
    FROM Employees2
    WHERE email LIKE @testuser + '%'
) as b
    ON b.full_name = a.full_name
```

Or perhaps you may just need a `UNION`:

```
SELECT full_name 
FROM Employees1
WHERE username = @testuser
UNION
SELECT full_name 
FROM Employees2
WHERE email LIKE @testuser + '%'
```

I added the full_name join condition, as I believe that is what you intended.

See [this db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/_RiQtait).